# Plot a graph using python2.7 for a program starting and ending at various timestamps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program that is starting and ending at various times and I have captured the timings.

**Example:**

```
[('05:43:44', '05:43:51'), ('05:59:32', '05:59:39'), ('06:14:46', '06:41:03'), ('06:41:16', '06:42:57')]
```

The start and end times are paired together for an instance in a tuple as shown below.

```
{ Example [(1st start time, 1st end time), (2nd start time, 2nd end time) ..and so on }
```

I want to plot the curve for the start, end times for the program and a meaningful graph. Please provide me ideas how to do plot this in Python 2.7.

I tried to run this, but get Value Error

Test Data:
  [('05:43:44', '05:59:32', '06:14:46', '06:41:16'),('05:43:51', '05:59:39', '06:41:03', '06:42:57')]*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(*zip(*zipped_files))
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-713cb20ee252> in <module>()
1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
2 
----> 3 plt.scatter(*zip(*zipped_files))
4 plt.show()
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05:43:44
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I indeed used matplotlib, but i face issues with that. The library is not able to parse timestamp values. I get error ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05:43:44. So i needed a way to handle these timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your data to datetime objects using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. Below is a complete example for the data you provided:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = [('05:43:44', '05:59:32', '06:14:46', '06:41:16'),('05:43:51', '05:59:39', '06:41:03', '06:42:57')]

x = [i[0] for i in data]
y = [i[1] for i in data]

new_x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S") for i in x]
new_y = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S") for i in y]

plt.plot(new_x,new_y)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

You can better format the x axis by using [`autofmt_xdate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(new_x,new_y)    
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks DavidG for the detailed info. I am using the code samples you provided.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question be sure to upvote / accept to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to generate a best fit for plotting start times against end times. You can use matplotlib to do this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
l = EXAMPLE LIST
starts = list(i[0] for i in l)
ends = list(i[1] for i in l)
plt.plot(starts, ends, -b)
plt.show()
```

You can use polyfit to generate best fit lines/curves as desired. Hope this helps at least give a general idea of what to do, even if it's not exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I indeed used matplotlib, but i face issues with that.     The library is not able to parse timestamp values.                                          I get error  ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05:43:44. So i needed a way to handle these timestamps.